# sql query to find the most popular hour

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Given a table with 2 columns

```
Name(type VARCHAR) Time(type DATETIME)
```

I need to write a SQL query to find the hour with largest number of entries.

For example:

```
Name   Time 
----   ----
a     12:30pm
b     12:05pm
c     13:55pm
d     12:50pm
e     01:02am
```

Desired result is the hour: 12pm - 1pm

My general idea is:
1) Group the rows by hour
2) count the rows / group
3) sort the counts in descending order
4) print the largest count

I need help converting this into an SQL query.

Comment: What is the type of your time column?

Comment: DATETIME. We can change the type to something else if it makes the query easier.

Comment: no datetime field is fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward...

```
SELECT HOUR(Time) as Hr,COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Hour(Time)
ORDER BY Cnt DESC
LIMIT 1
```

`GROUP BY Hour(Time)` - group by hours

`ORDER BY Cnt DESC` - this makes it sort by the count (in descending order)

`LIMIT 1` - as you only need one top result

Comment: As it's tagged also for Oracle, you would need TRUNC instead of HOUR, and use of ROWNUM and subquery instead of LIMIT clause.

Comment: it's actually tagged both mysql and oracle :/ so the syntax would differ. this one is correct for mysql

Comment: @poncha - please use apropriate syntax as your query will never work in Oracle. You may only confuse the OPs. This is regarding syntax only not code.

Answer (score 0):

This is Oracle version of what in my understanding you are looking for:

```
SELECT t_stamp
     , MAX(count(t_stamp)) OVER (PARTITION BY t_stamp ORDER BY t_stamp)  hits_per_hr_interval
  FROM
  (
  SELECT name, EXTRACT(hour From Cast(t_stamp as timestamp)) t_stamp
    FROM stack_test
  )
  GROUP BY t_stamp
  /

  T_STAMP    HITS_PER_HR_INTERVAL
  -------------------------------
  12          3
  13          2
```

OR using row_number():

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT t_stamp
      , Count(t_stamp) OVER (PARTITION BY t_stamp ORDER BY t_stamp) hits_per_hr_interval 
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t_stamp ORDER BY t_stamp) hr_seq
   FROM
   (
   SELECT EXTRACT(hour From Cast(t_stamp as timestamp)) t_stamp
     FROM stack_test
   )
  )
  -- WHERE hr_seq = 1  -- optional to see only first row per group as in above example 
  /

 T_STAMP    HITS_PER_HR_INTERVAL    HR_SEQ
 ------------------------------------------
 12         3                       1
 12         3                       2
 12         3                       3
 13         2                       1
 13         2                       2
```

You can add more filters like where your hours is between 12 and 1 only...